# javascript loop arithmetical progression

Tags: javascript

I have the javascript Div moving animation.

```
function move(elem) {

var left = -5

function frame() {

left--  // update parameters 

elem.style.left = left + 'px' // show frame 

if (left == -960)  // check finish condition
  clearInterval(id)
}
var id = setInterval(frame, 10) // draw every 10ms
}
```

It works fine, but it's too slow.
the var ' left ' is changing like: -5, -6, -7..
I need to change it like -5, -10, -15..
So I need something like that:

```
 left--(5)
```

Tryed many things, nothing works.
Hope you understand.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I need something like that:
>
> ```
> left--(5)
> ```

You want

```
left -= 5;
```

which is short for

```
left = left - 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I misunderstood this, but to decrease `left` by 5 is just

```
   left = left - 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var left;
var step=-5
function frame(){
 left-=step;
 // rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: That would increase `left` in every frame.